# ReflectionException - Class does not exist error after 2.2.5 from 2.1.9

Tags: magento2.2, upgrade, setup-di-compile

I have upgraded a Magento 2.1.9 store to 2.2.5.  The upgrade seems successful, and everything is working in development mode, but I am not able to compile or put the store into production mode.

The error I get when running `setup:di:compile` is:

```
[ReflectionException]Class Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface does not exist
```

I have removed the contents of `var/`, `generated/`, `generation/` etc, and set filesystem permissions specified in the documentation.

The full stack trace for the error is here:

```
[ReflectionException]
Class Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface does not exist


Exception trace:
() at /var/www/html/magento2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29 
ReflectionParameter->getClass() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29
Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassReaderDecorator.php:35

Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassReaderDecorator->getConstructor() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/Decorator/Area.php:53
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\Decorator\Area->getList() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:109
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->getDefinitionsCollection() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/Area.php:84
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\Area->doOperation() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:206
Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:241
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/magento-2.2/bin/magento:23

setup:di:compile
```

Any help with working out the cause of this error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have redis running? Try clearing redis cache

Comment: Hi Sulman,
Thanks for your input, however I don't have any external caching on this as it is a dev environment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.2.2 has changed Class name for `CacheInterface`

Previously, it was `Magento\Framework\Acl\CacheInterface` which is changed to `Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface`

So, you will require to update the class name in your code if you are upgrading your magento version to **2.2.2** or above.

Answer (score 1):

In magento 2, we need to upgrade 2.1.9 to 2.2.5 forcefully. As magento does not upgrade it directly.

So as you upgraded magento to 2.2.5 then `/setup` folder classes still uses 2.1.9.

So simply download `2.2.5` magento2 and copy `setup` folder content of 2.2.5 and paste into 2.1.9.

You could directly paste into `setup` folder or can copy old `setup` and paste new one as fresh `setup` folder.

Clear cache, generation etc and run.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this one out.  For anybody else running into a similar problem
Be careful when running grep to find the offending module.

I was using:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l  'Acl\CacheInterface' {} \;
```

but this didn't find any matches, as the backslash needs escaping:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l  'Acl\\CacheInterface' {} \;
```